# Can you enchant spiked gauntlets as weapons?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, weapons

One of my players wants to play an unarmed fighter. What I need to know is; do spiked gauntlets count as weapons or as armor for the purposes of enchanting?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They count as weapons, and can be enhanced as such.

The problem is that they count as separate weapons from Unarmed Strikes, which means anything he does to improve Unarmed Strikes is not going to improve his Spiked Gauntlets. If he’s planning on Monk or anything similar, I strongly recommend that you ignore this fact entirely and houserule that they take on the damage of his Unarmed Strike if it is higher than the Spiked Gauntlets would be.

Comment: Not a problem if he uses plain *Gauntlet* - "A strike with a gauntlet is otherwise considered an unarmed attack".

Comment: @JeorMattan Define "otherwise" there: I'd think that it would only include things not otherwise described... which the Gauntlet's damage is.

Comment: Away from books atm, but if I recall correctly, it describes only damage type, not the exact amount of damage, which falls into the "otherwise" area.

Comment: You do not recall correctly.

Comment: @mxyzplk Well, the description itself mentions only the damage type, saying that they otherwise act as an unarmed strike.  The weapons table lists both the unarmed strike and gauntlet as dealing the same damage, so it seems a stretch to say that the "otherwise" does not refer to damage.  The FAQ agrees with me here (p21), though it points out that gauntlets are not monk weapons.

Comment: No weapon descriptions note the damage. And which FAQ are you talking about?  The normal core rulebook FAQ does not mention gauntlets. http://paizo.com/products/btpy88yj/faq?Pathfinder-Roleplaying-Game-Core-Rulebook#tabs I prefer to let gauntlets and other things use unarmed damage myself, but it's a house rule not RAW.

Comment: @mxyzplk Since the *description* doesn't specify an alternative damage, the phrase "otherwise considered an unarmed attack" is relevant to effects that alter unarmed strike damage.  Pointing to a table that *lists the same damage as an unarmed strike* is not convincing evidence otherwise!  Also, why are you referring to Pathfinder?  It's in the [3.5 D&D FAQ](http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/er/20030221a).

Comment: @starwed The table does specify a damage (and happening to be the same damage as a regular unarmed strike is hardly convincing see how few options there are in the first place), so the question is whether or not "otherwise" means "other than mentioned in this description" or "other than otherwise indicated between the table and description." It's unclear what it means. Also, the FAQ is not RAW and is frequently wrong, which makes it a weak source.

Comment: @KRyan Suppose I have an effect that increases unarmed strike damage.  Does it increase the damage done by gauntlets?  Obviously, since it is considered an unarmed strike.  When I look at the gauntlet description as a whole, it's not even a little ambiguous to me: `(1)` It "lets you do lethal damage *with your unarmed strikes*".  `(2)` It is "otherwise considered an unarmed strike."   Yes, damage for a gauntlet is listed in the table of weapons, but so is damage for an unarmed strike.

Comment: @starwed: Your obvious is not obvious at all. **The rules are unclear.** It is certainly considered an unarmed strike for the purposes of, e.g., a feat that requires you make an unarmed attack. But whether or not "otherwise" ignores the table is very unclear. I would argue that it most likely does not. Why even *have* the table entry? You could just add it as a part of the Unarmed Strike's entry that "a Medium character deals 1d3 points of damage with an unarmed strike; this damage is nonlethal if the hand is bare, and lethal if the character is wearing gauntlets."